# Unable to get full length message

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have implemented a logic to get the message from a byte array.

```
public getInfo(byte[] hi) {

        type = ....

        sequence = ....

        int ack = ....

        int lastbyte = ....;

        int isUTF8byte = .....;

        actual_msg += (char) hi[CHAR1];
        actual_msg += (char) hi[CHAR2];
        actual_msg += (char) hi[CHAR3];
        actual_msg += (char) hi[CHAR4];
        actual_msg += (char) hi[CHAR5];
    }
```

The problem is it only gives me first five characters of the message. I mean if the byte array contains `Hello How are you`, I only get the output as `Hello`. The byte array has 3rd to 7th byte(5 bytes) with char messages.

I think the logic for remaining chars in the message should be inside a `for` loop because currently I have logic to read just first 5 chars. The 0th to 2nd byte is same for all sets of messages. Only the 3rs to 7th byte is of my concern.

How can I implement this?

Comment: If the `byte[]` is 7 bytes long, how do you expect it to hold "Hello How are you"?

Comment: No I mean the size isnt 7 bytes. The fields of the byte array has 3rd to 7th byte as char messages. I edited my question. Sorry

Comment: It still sounds like you don't have enough `byte`s. To get "Hello How are you" you will need to use `byte`s 3 through 19 (assuming I counted correctly). Is the message limited to 7 bytes, or is there room for more data?

Comment: This is just a message frame of 7 bytes. In 1 message, there can be 2000 frames. 1 frame says hello, next frame as 'how a', next as 'ryou.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want something like

```
public String getMessage(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(); 
    int index = 0
    while (index < bytes.length) {
        byte[] partOfMessage = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, index + 3, index + 7);
        message.append(new String(partOfMessage , StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        index += 7;
    }
    return message.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching for this:

```
byte [] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytearray, startpos, endpos);
String str = new String(subArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: `byte [] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytearray, startpos, endpos);`
This creates a subArray (extracts the message) of your array.

`String str = new String(subArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`
This converts is to a string